# ROS pocketsphinx + gstreamer record utterances to wav files

Tags: python, ros, pocketsphinx

I am working on a dialogue system where I need to get as input both ASR results as well as the the corresponding audio file. 
I use ROS indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 and I edit recognizer.py 
(http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/pocketsphinx/html/recognizer_8py_source.html)
in order to receive both text from ASR and the audio file for each recognized utterance.
I changed the gst pipeline to:

```
    self.launch_config += " ! audioconvert ! audioresample  ! tee name=t ! queue ! audioresample " \
                        + '! vader name=vad auto-threshold=true ' \
                        + '! pocketsphinx name=asr ! fakesink dump=1 t. ! valve drop=0 ! queue ! wavenc ! filesink location=test.wav async=0'
```

but what I managed to do is to record all the audio signal until the recognizer stops (eg. ^C). 
Moreover I tried to use after

self.pipeline.set_property('rawlogdir', 'folder_name/')  line 101

but it seems that GstPipeline does not have property `rawlogdir'

What I need is just get the audio signal of the recognized utterance, needed for audio processing (emotion recognition) using ROS pocketsphinx node.

Any ideas would be really helpful!

Comment: Unfortunately ROS pocketsphinx needs more work

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'vader' plugin to get the audio detected in .raw format.

Just add these lines to your code

```
self.vader = self.pipeline.get_by_name('vad')
self.vader.set_property('dump-dir', audio_dir )
```

and 'audio_dir' is where you want to save the files. To play the audio remember that pocketsphinx use 16-bit PCM audio at 8kHz.

For more information about GStreamer plugins use

```
$ gst-inspect-0.10 pocketsphinx
$ gst-inspect-0.10 vader
```